# Inserting div position and size attributes into MySQL database. How to gather info with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, attributes, element

I'm putting together a caption system for my site. When the user is finished with their caption and would like to submit, I need a way to insert the width, height, and position (left and right attributes) into my database.

I know I can detect element attributes using JavaScript, but this won't help me as inserting into the database is done using PHP. How can I detect these attributes in PHP and store them as variables to input into my database?

Any help would be appreciate. Let me know if you want any additional info. Thanks!

Comment: Using Javascript (*jQuery for brevity*) you can capture the CSS properties, and append them to your request body (*`POST` I'm assuming*) as a JSON collection. This would likely be easiest (*again, using jQuery*) and most UI intuitive via AJAX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have an `onsubmit()` handler in your form, in which you can get all the required attributes using javascript and inject into hidden fields.

Now when form is submitted, you can access these values on server side using PHP.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Just want to make sure I have this right: `<form onSubmit="func()">` And the function would basically just change the value of the hidden input fields. I'm just concerned about whether or not it would add to those fields before the form actually submits. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes it will. Your form will actually submit only after `func()` has been completely executed. That's what it is there for.

Comment: Alright. Just working on that now. I'll let you know how it goes. Thanks!